# use returned random number in if statement

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to generate a random number between 1 and 9 and respond to the outcome of it, but I cannot assign the number because it's a method.

```
static int number(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random(); 
    return random.Next(1, 9);
} 

if (number = 1)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

What should I change to make it work?

Edit: I cut out this part of the code because of the lenght otherwise, but I didn't call the if statement like that.

Comment: Uhm ... have you tried `number(1,9)` instead? And I think you meant to write `random.Next(min,max)`. Also `number == 1` instead of `number = 1`.

Comment: I've tried it that way, but the == cannot be applied to operands of type method or int, and with a singe =, it's the same result as my code

Comment: Did you fix all the other issues I mentioned?

Comment: FYI - if you want a number between 1 and 9, you should actually use `.Next(1,10)` since the upper bound is exclusive.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2):

Try this below

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            if (number(1, 9) == 1) // number is a function, not a variable
            {
                // Do Stuff
            }

        }

        static int number(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DirkHeijnen: thanks friend. I also have same question in my mind :)

Comment: Dear downvoter, could you please tell me the reason for downvoting?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but its probably worth putting the return value into a variable. Otherwise this answer *seems* to promote `else if (number(1,9)==2){...}` which would be incorrect since it would retrieve a different random number on each subsequent call. Also putting `new Random()` inside the method call is incorrect as well... It should be a static class member.

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to get fix it but its not the same Methode, so i dont know do u need the same method or not and , how many numbers do u want to get out ? Try this .

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace test6
    {
        class Program
        {
            static char randomNumber(string s)
            {

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int index = rnd.Next(0, s.Length);
                return s[index];
            }

            char number = randomNumber("123456789");
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(randomNumber("123456789"));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```